# What happens when a local jar contains class file with the same name as one in the java library?

Tags: java

My particular case deals with a class called `Point2D` thats in a local jar that i included in my project , however ,i also noticed that java has its own `Point2D` inside `java.awt.geom` . I understand that for this particular case , since i dont import `java.awt.geom` , so when i write `Point2D` it will be from my own package ? But if i did have to import `java.awt.geom` or be in a position where due to an import , i have similarly named class files in both local jar and java library , what will happen then ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the package names are different you can reference both with their fully qualified class names

```
java.awt.geom.Point2D jdkPoint2d = new ...;
com.mycompany.geometries.Point2D ourPoint2d = new ...;
```

You can also `import` one of them and use its simple class name and use the fully qualified class name of the other.